# Quadrature for numerically evaluating Cauchy integral formula using unit circle as closed contour

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, quantum-mechanics, cauchy-integral-formula, quadrature

I am currently trying to evaluate the derivatives of a function $F(z)$ in z=0, which is only known numerically on the unit circle ("$UC$") in the complex plane. My question is this:

given $z=\mathrm{e}^{-iwT}$ on $UC$ and Cauchy's integral formula, we get

\begin{equation}
F^{(n)}(z=0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{UC} \frac{F(z)}{z^{n+1}}\mathrm{d}z = -\frac{\omega}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi/\omega}F(\mathrm{e}^{-i\omega T})\mathrm{e}^{in\omega T} \mathrm{d}T\\ =-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}F(\mathrm{e}^{-i\tilde{T}})\mathrm{e}^{in\tilde{T}} \mathrm{d}\tilde{T}.
\end{equation}
Does anybody know of any quadrature schemes fitting for evaluating the above expression without too many sampling points? Im thinking there might be something equivalent to e.g. Gauss-Laguerre quadrature, but with another weight-function? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

For anybody curious about what it is for, the derivatives of $F$ in $z=0$ are actually Greens functions of a perturbed quantum system in the adiabatic limit. The order of derivative is related to how many photons are absorped/emitted. $F$ is actually matrix valued and will consume a lot of RAM, which is why i would like to keep the sampling points to a minimum. $F$ is formally a Laurent-series on the form $F(z,E) = \sum _{n=-\infty}^{\infty}z^n G_n(E)$, where the $G_n$'s are various Greens functions of the system.

Answer (score 2):

The trapezoidal rule would be ideal here, because the function is periodic (as well as smooth) and this rule converges almost exponentially fast for such functions.

Comment: I think the trapezoidal rule converges quadratically in the sampling size, and im not entirely sure it leverages the periodicity? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule

Comment: It is quadratic if you apply it on an interval. On the circle it becomes exponential. It's a well known fact. You can prove it by the Euler-Maclaurin formula.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt know trapezoidal sampling behaved like this on periodic functions!